# What is the best way to create make profile for user in Django? When i am extending AbstractUser in models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am totally confused here. I am working with Django and Django rest framework. I want to create profile for users but i am not understanding.
Here is the code I am trying.
Thanks for help.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# Create your models here.
from django.conf import settings

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=480, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**Please help me, Is this a right way to implement this?**

I also tried to do this.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=480, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And then run command **python manage.py migrate**. It's migrated successfully but i can't see any field when i open user in Django admin panel. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? You never state it. Your code appears to be fine...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Can i add fields and extends In class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass or should I create like this class Profile(models.Model): . I am worried that i am doing it right or not. Thanks

Comment: Yes you can add fields in your `CustomUser` class.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I did something like this  `class CustomUser(AbstractUser): bio = models.TextField()` and then migrate but i can't see anything in Django Admin. Thanks

Comment: You would need to modify the model admin of the default User admin and register it, check [Custom users and django.contrib.admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin). Also have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to your Custom user model? Also your current example of keeping the profile as a separate model is good, why put it in the user model?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for help. I was not clear about the approach. I mean which one is better for long run.    This is my Admin.py file code. `from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from users.models import CustomUser, Profile
# Register your models here.

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ["username", "email","is_staff"]

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)`